# Bayesian Hierarchical Clustering: How to calculate probability of Data under $H_1$?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-bayesian, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on implementing the Bayesian hierarchical clustering algorithm found [here](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~kheller/bhcnew.pdf) from scratch as a way to practice and learn the algorithm. However, I have hit a snag in calculating the quantity in formula 1 of section 2:

\begin{align}
p(D_k|H_1^k) &= \int p(D_k|\theta) p(\theta |\beta) d\theta\\
&= \int \left[ \prod_{x_i \in D_k} p(x_i |\theta) \right] p(\theta | \beta) d\theta
\end{align}

In the subsequent paragraph, the authors state,

> This is a natural model-based criterion for measuring how well the data
>   fit into one cluster. If we choose models with conjugate priors (e.g. Normal-Inverse-Wishart priors for Normal continuous data or Dirichlet priors for Multinomial discrete data) this integral is tractable

I understand that this is the probability of cluster $k$ being generated from some distribution with parameter(s) $\mathbf{\theta}$ and that, on the first iteration of the algorithm, I should be calculating this quantity for every pair of data points (i.e. vectors) in the set.

However, I am a bit confused regarding the quote above. Does this mean that I should replace the contents of the integral with an appropriate posterior distribution and then perform the integration with respect to $\mathbf{\theta}$?

What would this mean in the Gaussian example mentioned by the authors:

> For example, in the case of Gaussians, $p(D_k|H_1^k)$ is a function of the sample mean and covariance of the data in $D_k$

The paper seems to allude to this being a straight-forward calculation, but I have not seen conjugate priors used in this way. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this isn't too late to help! In short, yes, you have what I believe is the right idea.

I've been messing around with this a little bit myself, and what's being referenced here is the fact that the [marginal likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood) (the integral expression you provide) has a quick-to-evaluate closed form that only makes use of the sample statistics of $D_{k}$ when the conjugate prior is employed, no numerical integration required.

Rather than do the mathematical legwork, I'll point you to a [resource](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) for the multivariate Gaussian/Normal-Inverse-Wishart case. See Section 9, and specifically, the derivation of the marginal likelihood in 9.5. It can be a little hard to read because the notation is sprinkled throughout the reference, but ultimately, you just need to compute expression 266.

One more tangentially-related thing. Practically speaking, you'll actually want to be dealing with the marginal log-likelihood, as the gamma function risks overflow. I heartily recommend you compute the (pseudo?)log-odds to make BHC merge decisions: $$\log(P(D_{k}|H_{1}^{k})P(H_{1}^{k})) - \log(P(D_{k}|H_{2}^{k})P(H_{2}^{k}))$$
Then, you can just plug the marginal log-likelihood right in.

Forgive any flubs, this is my first StackExchange-style response.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE and thank you for your answer. If you want, you may take the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).